# What's the proper way to build a data template for a TreeView node that contains multiple collections as children?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a class that contains multiple collections of properties:

```
class Foo{
   public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
   public ObservableCollection<Baz> Bazzes {get; set;}
}
```

I'm trying to display this in a `TreeView`, where the `Foo` node is at the root, and then under it is a node for the `Bars` collection containing each of the `Bar` elements as subnodes, and the same for the `Bazzes` collection. But I can't seem to get the data template right.  The closest I've managed to get is like so:

```
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Foo}">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Bars" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bars}"/>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Bazzes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bazzes}"/>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Bar}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" (" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text=")" Foreground="Blue" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Baz}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

This displays a hierarchical tree with nodes I can open to display sub-items by clicking the little triangle, but when I try to click on any of the items, it selects the entire `Foo` *with all of its sub-items* as one big selection.  I'm assuming this is because the nodes containing the collections are integrated into the template for `Foo` and so it's treating them as all being one big node somehow?  But I don't know how to get the collections to show up as sub-nodes without doing it that way.

What's the correct way to do the type of setup I'm looking for, since this is obviously not quite right?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of fundamental issues with your implementation.  The first is that the Tree is simply a map onto the bound data structure which is expected to be a tree.  First we have to make your Foo class a tree...

```
public class BarBazBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

}
public class Bar : BarBazBase
{
    public string BarSpecial { get; set; }
}
public class Baz : BarBazBase
{
    public string BazSpecial { get; set; }
}


public class Foo : ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<BarBazBase>>
{
    public ObservableCollection<BarBazBase> Bars { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<BarBazBase>();
    public ObservableCollection<BarBazBase> Bazzes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<BarBazBase>();
    public Foo()
    {
        Add(Bars);
        Add(Bazzes);
    }
}
```

Next we need a different template for each type of tree node.  We therefore need a data template selector

```
public class BasBazTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = container as FrameworkElement;
        if(item is Foo)
        {
            return fe.FindResource("TreeHeader") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is ObservableCollection<BarBazBase> baseCollection)
        {
            if (baseCollection.Count > 0 && baseCollection[0] is Bar)
                return fe.FindResource("BarHeader") as DataTemplate;
            else if (baseCollection.Count > 0 && baseCollection[0] is Baz)
                return fe.FindResource("BazHeader") as DataTemplate;
            else
                return null;
        }
        else if (item is Bar)
        {
            return fe.FindResource("BarItemTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        else if (item is Baz)
        {
            return fe.FindResource("BazItemTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we are ready to pull everything together in XAML...

```
       <TreeView x:Name="treeView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Beige"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Root}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource BasBazTemplateSelector}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeHeader" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BazHeader" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <Label>Baz</Label>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BarHeader" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <Label>Bar</Label>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="BarItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" (" Foreground="Blue" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Foreground="Blue" />
                    <TextBlock Text=")" Foreground="Blue" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="BazItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

A few loose ends...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BasBazTemplateSelector x:Key="BasBazTemplateSelector"/>
</Window.Resources>

public Foo Root { get; set; }

        Root = new Foo();
        Root.Bars.Add(new Bar() { Name = "a", Type = "a0", BarSpecial = "a bar" });
        Root.Bars.Add(new Bar() { Name = "b", Type = "b0", BarSpecial = "another bar" });
        Root.Bazzes.Add(new Baz() { Name = "c", Type = "c0", BazSpecial = "a baz" });
        Root.Bazzes.Add(new Baz() { Name = "d", Type = "d0", BazSpecial = "another baz" });
```

This is the result...

[image]

Comment: That kinda works, but is there any way to do this without shoehorning all the elements into a common base class?  This feels a bit hacky.  Can it be kept heterogeneous?

Comment: @MasonWheeler yes.  This type of mapping a tree view onto a non-tree data structure happens all the time.  What you are missing is a view model., the connecting element in the MVVM pattern.  So in this approach your Foo class remains unchanged and you create a new class, say FooViewModel, that is a tree that has references to your model.  FooViewModel then becomes the data source of the tree.  I could have written a view model for you but this would have taken more code.